# Does the Apple Smart Keyboard work for all iPads?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I have an iPad 7th gen 10.2" and I've been looking for apple smart keyboards for a few days now. I came across one on ebay which was cheaper than usual but the thing is, it says that it's for the iPad 10.5".

How can I know if this works only in a 10.5" air or pro model, or it doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. The contacts and physical size of keyboards make it very unlikely you can swap parts. Make sure the return policy is good or use the [Apple Store app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948) on your iPad and link your device so it shows which parts are compatible with your device.

[image]